# NLog не пишет лог, если я запускаю тесты в mstest.exe через CMD

Tags: c#, nlog

NLog не пишет лог, если я запускаю тесты в mstest.exe через CMD, при этом пишет, если я запускаю тесты из Visual Studio.

Что нужно сделать, чтобы правильно работало из CMD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что mstest не переносит конфиг файл NLog.config в папку, из которой запускается тест. Кстати, туда же и сами логи будут писаться:

```
..\TestResults\ИМЯПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ_ИМЯКОМПЬЮТЕРА ДАТАВРЕМЯ\Out.
```

**Вариант 1.**

Записать конфигурацию NLog в файл App.config.

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog"/>
    </configSections>
    <nlog>
    </nlog>
</configSections>
```

**Вариант 2.**

Проставив атрибут, который копирует нужный файл:

```
[TestMethod()]
[DeploymentItem("NLog.config")]
public void TestMethod1()
{
}
```

**Вариант 3.**

Перейти на использование инструмента VSTest.Console.exe, которым пользуется студия начиная с 2012:

```
VSTest.Console.exe TestProject.dll
```

**Вариант 4.**

Добавить файл `local.testsettings`:

```
<TestSettings name="Local" id="00ebe0c6-7b64-49c0-80a5-09796270f111" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
    <Description>These are default test settings for a local test run.</Description>
    <Deployment>
        <DeploymentItem filename="NLog.config" outputDirectory=".\"/>
    </Deployment>
</TestSettings>
```

И вызывать команту mstest с новым параметром:

```
mstest /testcontainer:TestProject.dll /testsettings:local.testsettings
```

---

Попробуйте изменить свойсто `Copy to Output Directory` для файла, в котором у вас настройки `NLog` (`App.config` или `NLog.config`), на `Copy Always` или `Copy if Newer`.

Comment: У NLog.config стоит Copy Always и он копируется в папку к бинарникам

Comment: @tCode А какая команда для запуска mstest используется?

Comment: mstext.exe /testcontainer:SolutionName\bin\Release\SolutionName.dll /nologo, где SolutionName - имя сборки

Comment: А вы давно пересобирали под Release?

Comment: Батник делает ребилд при каждом запуске: devenv.exe SolutionName.sln /rebuild Release

Comment: @tCode Внес исправления в ответ.

Comment: Спасибо! Воспользовался вторым вариантом